# WPF Resources in class library in .NET 5

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-5, class-library

Before, in .NET Framework, when I created a WPF class library, I had my **App.xaml** (set as **Application definition**) referencing my resource dictionaries like that:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary1.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary2.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary3.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

However, now, with .NET 5, I get this compilation error:

> Library project file cannot specify ApplicationDefinition element.

So that message means I can't have an **App.xaml** file in a class library anymore. But now, I don't know how to define my resources globally in a class library. Isn't there any way to do this without referencing the dictionaries in each and every XAML file in the project?

*Edit*: It's not about the `Source` syntax. The path is correct and everything compiles perfectly if I set the project to **Windows Application** instead of **Class Library**.

Comment: The .net type of the class library must be the same as the type of project.

Comment: Write what platforms your project is targeting.

Comment: @EldHasp I used the default .NET 5 WPF class library template
`<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>`
`<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>`
And I try to compile in Debug for Any CPU. But the problem occurs also on x64.

Comment: I tried to somehow solve this problem, but nothing worked for me.
Perhaps in Core this is really unacceptable and requires a different approach.

Comment: Just to clarify - are you having trouble referencing a resource dictionary from another dictionary defined in the library, or referencing resources defined in the library from a different project/application consuming the library?

Comment: How do you want to use this Resources, defined in App.xaml in a library? I mean what is your start project then and entry point?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I have the same error for .NET framework library.

Answer (score 2):

refering to that github issue : https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2812#issuecomment-607537794

> In an SDK style WindowsDesktop project,
>
> *.xaml are all treated as Page items by default, unless they are named App.xaml (C#) or Application.xaml (VB).
>
> App.xaml/Application.xaml is treated as ApplicationDefinition by default.

```
<!-- 
Disables automatic globbing of App.xaml/Application.xaml into 
ApplicationDefinition item
App.xaml/Application.xaml would now get treated as any other *.xaml file 
(typically, a Page)
--> 
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnableDefaultApplicationDefinition>false</EnableDefaultApplicationDefinition>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Worth a try.

Comment: check how your App.xaml is referenced  too:
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="App.xaml" />
  </ItemGroup>

Answer (score -1):

For me works the following: If you have library-project with resources (i.e. namespace "**Project.Resources**") and have presentation-project (i.e. namespace "**Project.Presentation**"):

```
<Application x:Class="Project.Presentation.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Project.Resources;Dictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Don't forget to add reference to "Project.Resources" in "Project.Presentation".